How to replace/fix PrefabUtility.SaveAsPrefabAsset?
So I was making a simple game and one of the things I wanted was that you would be able to choose a skin for when you play and it works, but only in the editor since I didn't know that building it would make it so that function doesn't work anymore/you just can't (a bit dumb now that i think of it, but wasn't really thinking about that being the problem).
So I wanted to know if there was a way to make it so this function can work (since I saw someone say they just added a editor file, but they never explained much and it was vague so idk) or a way of reworking it to not use the editor.
Here is the code for both the player selection and the player character (I'm fairly new to this so the code is probably very clunky and not effective so sorry in advance)
Skin Selection
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class skinManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SpriteRenderer sr;
    public SpriteRenderer sLeft;
    public SpriteRenderer sLeftD;
    public SpriteRenderer sDown;
    public SpriteRenderer sRightD;
    public SpriteRenderer sRight;
    public SpriteRenderer sRightU;
    public SpriteRenderer sUp;
    public SpriteRenderer sLeftU;
    public List<Sprite> skins = new List<Sprite>(); 
    public List<Sprite> left = new List<Sprite>();
    public List<Sprite> leftD = new List<Sprite>();
    public List<Sprite> down = new List<Sprite>();
    public List<Sprite> rightD = new List<Sprite>();
    public List<Sprite> right = new List<Sprite>();
    public List<Sprite> rightU = new List<Sprite>();
    public List<Sprite> up = new List<Sprite>();
    public List<Sprite> leftU = new List<Sprite>();
    private int selectedSkin = 0;
    private int selLeft = 0;
    private int selLeftD = 0;
    private int selDown = 0;
    private int selRightD = 0;
    private int selRight = 0;
    private int selRightU = 0;
    private int selUp = 0;
    private int selLeftU = 0;
    public GameObject playerSkin;
    public GameObject playerLeft;
    public GameObject playerLeftD;
    public GameObject playerDown;
    public GameObject playerRightD;
    public GameObject playerRight;
    public GameObject playerRightU;
    public GameObject playerUp;
    public GameObject playerLeftU;

    public void NextOption()
    {
        selectedSkin = selectedSkin + 1;
        selLeft = selLeft + 1;
        selLeftD = selLeftD + 1;
        selDown = selDown + 1;
        selRightD = selRightD + 1;
        selRight = selRight + 1;
        selRightU = selRightU + 1;
        selUp = selUp + 1;
        selLeftU = selLeftU + 1;
        if(selectedSkin == skins.Count)
        {
            selectedSkin = 0;
            selLeft = 0;
            selLeftD = 0;
            selDown = 0;
            selRightD = 0;
            selRight = 0;
            selRightU = 0;
            selUp = 0;
            selLeftU = 0;
        }
        sr.sprite = skins[selectedSkin];
        sLeft.sprite = left[selectedSkin];
        sLeftD.sprite = leftD[selectedSkin];
        sDown.sprite = down[selectedSkin];
        sRightD.sprite = rightD[selectedSkin];
        sRight.sprite = right[selectedSkin];
        sRightU.sprite = rightU[selectedSkin];
        sUp.sprite = up[selectedSkin];
        sLeftU.sprite = leftU[selectedSkin];
    }

    public void BackOption()
    {
        selectedSkin = selectedSkin - 1;
        selLeft = selLeft - 1;
        selLeftD = selLeftD - 1;
        selDown = selDown - 1;
        selRightD = selRightD - 1;
        selRight = selRight - 1;
        selRightU = selRightU - 1;
        selUp = selUp - 1;
        selLeftU = selLeftU - 1;
        if(selectedSkin < 0)
        {
            selectedSkin = skins.Count - 1;
            selLeft = left.Count - 1;
            selLeftD = leftD.Count - 1;
            selDown = down.Count - 1;
            selRightD = rightD.Count - 1;
            selRight = right.Count - 1;
            selRightU = rightU.Count - 1;
            selUp = up.Count - 1;
            selLeftU = leftU.Count - 1;
        }
        sr.sprite = skins[selectedSkin];
        sLeft.sprite = left[selectedSkin];
        sLeftD.sprite = leftD[selectedSkin];
        sDown.sprite = down[selectedSkin];
        sRightD.sprite = rightD[selectedSkin];
        sRight.sprite = right[selectedSkin];
        sRightU.sprite = rightU[selectedSkin];
        sUp.sprite = up[selectedSkin];
        sLeftU.sprite = leftU[selectedSkin];
    }

    public void Select()
    {
        PrefabUtility.SaveAsPrefabAsset(playerSkin, "Assets/selectedskin.prefab");
        PrefabUtility.SaveAsPrefabAsset(playerLeft, "Assets/selLeft.prefab");
        PrefabUtility.SaveAsPrefabAsset(playerLeftD, "Assets/selLeftD.prefab");
        PrefabUtility.SaveAsPrefabAsset(playerDown, "Assets/selDown.prefab");
        PrefabUtility.SaveAsPrefabAsset(playerRightD, "Assets/selRightD.prefab");
        PrefabUtility.SaveAsPrefabAsset(playerRight, "Assets/selRight.prefab");
        PrefabUtility.SaveAsPrefabAsset(playerRightU, "Assets/selRightU.prefab");
        PrefabUtility.SaveAsPrefabAsset(playerUp, "Assets/selUp.prefab");
        PrefabUtility.SaveAsPrefabAsset(playerLeftU, "Assets/selLeftU.prefab");
    }
}

Player Control
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool gameStarted = false;
    private bool noReset = false;
    public GameObject selectedskin;
    public GameObject selLeft;
    public GameObject selLeftD;
    public GameObject selLeftU;
    public GameObject selRight;
    public GameObject selRightD;
    public GameObject selRightU;
    public GameObject selDown;
    public GameObject selUp;
    private Sprite left;
    private Sprite right;
    private Sprite down;
    private Sprite up;
    private Sprite leftDown;
    private Sprite rightDown;
    private Sprite leftUp;
    private Sprite rightUp;
    private Sprite stare;
    private int sceneID = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        stare = selectedskin.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;
        left = selLeft.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;
        right = selRight.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;
        down = selDown.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;
        up = selUp.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;
        leftDown = selLeftD.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;
        rightDown = selRightD.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;
        leftUp = selLeftU.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;
        rightUp = selRightU.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;
    }

    void Update()
    {
     if (gameStarted)
     {
      float moveX = 0f;
      float moveY = 0f;  
      float moveSpeed = 6f;
      if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) 
      {
          moveY = +1f;
          gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite=up;
      } 
      if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
      {
          moveY = +1f;
          gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite=up;
      }
      if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) 
      {
          moveX = -1f;
          gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite=left;
      }
      if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) 
      {
          moveX = -1;
          gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite=left;
      }
      if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) 
      {
          moveY = -1f;
          gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite=down;
      }
      if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow)) 
      {
          moveY = -1f;
          gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite=down;
      }
      if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) 
      {
          moveX = +1f;
          gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite=right;
      }
      if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)) 
      {
          moveX = +1f;
          gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite=right;
      }
      if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)&&Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
      {gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite=leftUp;}
      if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)&&Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
      {gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite=rightUp;}
      if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)&&Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
      {gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite=leftUp;}
      if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)&&Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
      {gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite=rightUp;}
      if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)&&Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
      {gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite=leftDown;}
      if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)&&Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
      {gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite=rightDown;}
      if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow)&&Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
      {gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite=leftDown;}
      if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow)&&Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
      {gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite=rightDown;}
      if(!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)&&!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)&&!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)&&!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)&&!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)&&!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)&&!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow)&&!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
      {gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite=stare;}
      Vector3 moveDir = new Vector3(moveX, moveY).normalized;
      transform.position += moveDir * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime; 
     }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && !noReset)
    {
        GameStart();
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R) && noReset && !gameStarted)
    {
        RestartScene();
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
        HomeScreen();
    }
    }

    public void HomeScreen()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneID);
    }

    void GameStart()
    {
          gameStarted = true;
          noReset = true;
    }
   
     void GameEnd()
     {
          gameStarted = false;
     }
   
     void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
     {
          if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("enemy"))
          {
               GameEnd();
          }
     } 

     public void RestartScene()
     {
          SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
     }
}


In general I would recommend to introduce some serialzable class(es) to bundle fields that belong together and then further some dictionaries to store and access these things by e.g. an enum key

And then a bit unclear to me what exactly the usecase of prefabs you had in mind here .. you would probably rather just store this is PlayerPrefs and update the visuals accordingly ...

I could use PlayerPrefs, but I don't understand I guess I'll have to do deeper into it. Also for use case was mainly to swap colors. I had a sprite which had 6 possible colors and once you select a color you wanted it would save the prefab to that color and the player sprites uses those prefabs

I would simply not use prefabs for this but rather store this information e.g. in a ScriptableObject (if it is only for a session) or as said PlayerPrefs (if it is for storing persistent across sessions)

Ok then I feel like PlayerPrefs would work better, but could you elaborate on it more or find something so that I can understand it better

As I understand your code you have a set of sprites, one for each movement direction.
And then you have multiple different skins for those sets.
Rather than having multiple independent lists and hope they have the same amount of elements, this ensures there is always a full set of sprites belonging together.
So personally I would have such a class in the first place in order to structure things a bit better
// an enum to later on access sprites more easily
public enum MoveDirection
{
    Idle,
    Left,
    LeftDown,
    Down,
    RightDown,
    Right,
    RightUp,
    Up,
    LeftUp
}

// Class to hold all relevant information about one skin
// aka one set of sprites for instance
[Serializable]
public class Skin
{
    [SerializeField] private Sprite idle;
    [SerializeField] private Sprite left;
    [SerializeField] private Sprite leftDown;
    [SerializeField] private Sprite down;
    [SerializeField] private Sprite rightDown;
    [SerializeField] private Sprite right;
    [SerializeField] private Sprite rightUp;
    [SerializeField] private Sprite up;
    [SerializeField] private Sprite leftUp;

    public Sprite GetSprite(MoveDirection direction)
    {
        return direction switch
        {
            MoveDirection.Left => left,
            MoveDirection.LeftDown => leftDown,
            MoveDirection.Down => down,
            MoveDirection.RightDown => rightDown,
            MoveDirection.Right => right,
            MoveDirection.RightUp => rightUp,
            MoveDirection.Up => up,
            MoveDirection.LeftUp => leftUp,
            _ => idle;
        }
    }
}

Then for storing the sets it makes little sense to assign them to some prefab SpriteRenderers if you don't really use them but only use them to store a Sprite reference => Rather store the Sprite reference directly. I would use a ScriptableObject.
You could do this also directly in SkinManager but imho it is better and easier to store this on asset scope, decoupled of a specific Scene and SkinManager instance (you could in fact have one per scene this way and it would still work the same).
As mentioned a ScriptableObject can cary over values to other scenes - but only within this session of the application. So in order to store the index persistently across sessions you could additionally back it up through PlayerPrefs as this is just a visual setting and not any sensitive data.
[CreateAssetMenu]
public class SkinOptions : ScriptableObject
{
    // Key we will use to store and access the selected index via PlayerPrefs
    private const string PLAYER_PREFS_KEY = "SelectedSkinIndex";

    // Via the Inspector add the amount of skins you need and configure their sprites accordingly
    [SerializeField] private Skin[] availableSkins;

    // will store the current selected index and mirror the one stored in PlayerPrefs
    // doing this for a bit better performance and to make it appear in the Debug Inspector
    private int currentIndex;

    // Access the current selected skin directly
    public Skin CurrentSkin => availableSkins[currentIndex];

    // event others can listen to and get informed if the skin is changed during runtime
    public event Action<Skin> OnSkinSelectionChanged;

    // For ScriptableObjects this is called during the first loading of the app
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        // get the persistent stored index - fallback to 0
        currentIndex = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(PLAYER_PREFS_KEY, 0);

        // inform listeners (in case there are already some - depends on execution order)
        OnSkinSelectionChanged?.Invoke(CurrentSkin);
    }

    // increase the selected index, wraps around
    // updates local and persistent index value
    // informs listeners about change
    public void SetNextSkin()
    {
        // increase with wrap around 
        currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % availableSkins.Length;
 
        // also store in PlayPrefs
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt(PLAYER_PREFS_KEY, currentIndex);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();

        // inform listeners
        OnSkinSelectionChanged?.Invoke(CurrentSkin);
    }

    // increase the selected index, wraps around
    // updates local and persistent index value
    // informs listeners about change
    public void SetPreviousSkin()
    {
        // decrease with wrap around
        currentIndex -= 1;
        if(currentIndex < 0)
        {
            currentIndex = availableSkins.Length;
        }

        // also store in PlayPrefs
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt(PLAYER_PREFS_KEY, currentIndex);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();

        // inform listeners
        OnSkinSelectionChanged?.Invoke(CurrentSkin);
    }
}

To create an instance of this go to the Assets (ProjectView) -> right click -> Create -> SkinOptions.
And then in the player you can simply retrieve the Skin and react accordingly whenever a new skin is selected
// will be skipping unrelated code parts
public class Movement : MonoBehavior 
{
    // drag in the created SkinOptions from the assets
    [SerializeField] private SkinOptions skinOptions;
    // instead of GetComponent repeadely rather reference via the Inspector as well
    [SerializeField] private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;

    // runtime fields in order to react to either direction or skin change
    private MoveDirection currentDirection;
    private Skin currentSkin;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // as fallback if not referenced via Inspector use GetComponent ONCE
        if(!spriteRenderer) spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        // it is always save to remove a callback - this just ensures it is really added only ever once
        skinOptions.OnSkinSelectionChanged -= OnNewSkin;
        // listen to the change event
        skinOptions.OnSkinSelectionChanged += OnNewSkin;

        // as the event might have already been called while we were not subscribed yet
        // directly call the callback with the current value now as well
        OnNewSkin(skinOptions.CurrentSkin);
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        // always ensure to remove callbacks when not needed anymore
        // to save performance and also avoid errors (e.g. if this instance is destroyed due to scene switch)
        skinOptions.OnSkinSelectionChanged -= OnNewSkin;
    }

    // This is called whenever the skin was changed
    // stores the new skin and refreshes sprite
    private void OnNewSkin(Skin skin)
    {
        if(skin != currentSkin)
        {
            currentSkin = skin;
            UpdateSprite(); 
        }
    }

    // combine the currentSkin and currentDirection and refresh the sprite accordingly
    private void UpdateSprite()
    {
        spriteRenderer.sprite = currentSkin.GetSprite(currentDirection);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // horizontal and vertical axes by default react to both WASD and arrow keys so using them reduces complexity a lot for your case
        var input = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("vertical")), 1f);

        // apply movement
        transform.position += (Vector3)input * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        // calculate the direction from given input
        MoveDirection newDirection;

        if(Mathf.Approximately(input.sqrMagnitude, 0f))
        {
            newDirection = MoveDirection.Idle;
        }
        else
        {
            // angle between input direction and up
            var angle = Vector2.SignedAngle(input, Vector2.up);

            // map angle to the 8 move directions
            if(angle >= -22.5f && angle <= 22.5f) newDirection = MoveDirection.Up;
            else if(angle > 22.5f && angle <= 67.5f) newDirection = MoveDirection.RightUp;
            else if(angle > 67.5f && angle <= 112.5f) newDirection = MoveDirection.Right;
            else if(angle > 112.5f && angle <= 157.5f) newDirection = MoveDirection.RightDown;
            else if(angle < -22.5f && && angle >= -67.5f) newDirection = MoveDirection.LeftUp;
            else if(angle < -67.5f && angle >= -112.5f) newDirection = MoveDirection.Left;
            else if(angle < -112.5f && angle >= -157.5f) newDirection = MoveDirection.LeftDown;
            else newDirection = MoveDirection.Down;
        }

        // finally apply the direction
        // to save a bit performance only apply if direction actually changed
        if(newDirection != currentDirection)
        {
            currentDirection = newDirection;
            UpdateSprite();
        }

        // Skipping GameStart, Restart & home
    }
}


Hacked this down on my phone but I hope it gives you an idea and good start point

Thank you I’ll review this once I have the time, but this should be a great start point!

Better then mindlessly trying to find something in the internet that may or may not work/explain it wel
